# Compare list<object1> and list<object2>

Tags: c#, compare, listobject

---

colDiffUpdated and colDiffTarget have different values, How can I add to colTypes the difference of the two list?

> assume each list have different values.

```
   public List<columnTypes> colType = new List<columnTypes>();
            public List<coldiffTypes> colDiffUpdated = new List<coldiffTypes>();
            public List<coldiffTypesTarget> colDiffTarget = new List<coldiffTypesTarget>();
```

> this is the class where i store the value

```
public class columnTypes
    {
        public string tblName { get; set; }
        public string colName { get; set; }
        public int maxLength { get; set; }
        public string maxLengthStr { get; set; }
        public bool isUnique { get; set; }
        public bool isKey { get; set; }
        public System.Type dataType { get; set; }
        public bool isNullable { get; set; }
        public bool isAutoIncrement { get; set; }
        public string dataTypeName { get; set; }
        public int numericPrecision { get; set; }
        public int numericScale { get; set; }
    }

    public class coldiffTypes
    {
        public string tblName { get; set; }
        public string colName { get; set; }
        public int maxLength { get; set; }
        public string maxLengthStr { get; set; }
        public bool isUnique { get; set; }
        public bool isKey { get; set; }
        public System.Type dataType { get; set; }
        public bool isNullable { get; set; }
        public bool isAutoIncrement { get; set; }
        public string dataTypeName { get; set; }
        public int numericPrecision { get; set; }
        public int numericScale { get; set; }
    }

    public class coldiffTypesTarget
    {
        public string tblName { get; set; }
        public string colName { get; set; }
        public int maxLength { get; set; }
        public string maxLengthStr { get; set; }
        public bool isUnique { get; set; }
        public bool isKey { get; set; }
        public System.Type dataType { get; set; }
        public bool isNullable { get; set; }
        public bool isAutoIncrement { get; set; }
        public string dataTypeName { get; set; }
        public int numericPrecision { get; set; }
        public int numericScale { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Am I wrong, or are these three classes exactly the same? Why don't you use a single class for all three lists?

Comment: Are those classes generated somehow? Could they derive from one base class or at least implement the same interface?

Comment: Here not only value differs.. Entire contract is differing.

Comment: I see. I get it now .. assume that we have a 1 class ignore the coldiffTypes and coldiffTypesTarget . since they have same object have can i compare the public List<columnTypes> colDiffUpdated = new List<columnTypes>();
            public List<columnTypes> colDiffTarget = new List<columnTypes>(); if I use except or intersect it returns null..

Answer (score 0):

The classes look with same properties, if it is so, just implement one class IEqualityComparer and compare each value of that class of colDiffUpdated and colDiffTarget lists